# sql delete double output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a microsoft sql server. I need to do something along the lines of the following: (not working code, its just to get my point across)

```
DECLARE @old TABLE
  (
     locatie   NVARCHAR(256),
     gebruiker NVARCHAR(256),
     tijd      DATETIME
  )
DECLARE @tot INT

DELETE FROM dbo.DW_D_Locaties_Inpak_Productie
OUTPUT deleted.locatie,
       deleted.gebruiker,
       deleted.productiedatum
INTO @old (locatie, gebruiker, tijd)
OUTPUT Sum(deleted.aantal) INTO @tot
WHERE  DocumentNr = 'B424609'
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a valid syntax try this instead

```
DECLARE @old TABLE
  (
     locatie   NVARCHAR(256),
     gebruiker NVARCHAR(256),
     tijd      DATETIME,
     aantal    INT
  )
DECLARE @tot INT

DELETE FROM dbo.DW_D_Locaties_Inpak_Productie
OUTPUT deleted.locatie,
       deleted.gebruiker,
       deleted.productiedatum,
       deleted.aantal
INTO @old (locatie, gebruiker, tijd,aantal)
WHERE  DocumentNr = 'B424609'

SELECT @tot = Sum(aantal)
FROM   @old
```

Comment: like I said, I just put that semi-code there to get my point across. I've thought about this solution, but it just feels like a waste of memory as the aantal inside @old is not needed. I want to know the proper way of doing this.